# Python subprocess docker thread did not work

Tags: python-3.x, docker, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have a python flask app that runs shell command and it is handled by thread to process sync process.

```py
    def _upload_video_firebase(self, f1, f2, output_filename):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self._download_video, args=(f1,f2,output_filename,))
        print('threading')
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        # t.join()

    def overlay_video(self, f1,f2, output_filename):
        print('processing video')
        start_time = time.time()
        f1 = "'" + f1 + "'"
        f2 = 'API/video/input/{0}'.format(f2)

        if not os.path.exists('API/video/output'):
            os.makedirs('API/video/output')

        succ = True
        cmd=('ffmpeg -i {0} -vf "movie= {1} [a]; [in][a]overlay=0:0 [c]"  API/video/output/{2} '.format(f1,f2,output_filename))
        print(cmd)
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
            if p.wait() != 0:
                # Handle error / raise exception
                succ = False
                print ("There were some errors")
                print(stderrdata)
                return succ
            print('conversion success')

            file_path = 'API/video/output/{0}'.format(output_filename)
            succ = self.client.upload_video(file_path)
            print(succ)
            print("code_exc_time %s" % (time.time() - start_time))
            if succ:
                self.delete_file(file_path)

            return succ
        except OSError as e:
                errors = True
                print(e.strerror)
                # return e.strerror, errors

    def delete_file(self, file_path):
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print('deleted {0}'.format(file_path))
            os.remove(file_path)
```

Thread works fine when I use run flask without docker.
Docker file

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.7

# Indicate where uwsgi.ini lives
ENV UWSGI_INI uwsgi.ini

# Tell nginx where static files live.
ENV STATIC_URL /app/static

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set the folder where uwsgi looks for the app
WORKDIR /app

# If you have additional requirements beyond Flask (which is included in the
# base image), generate a requirements.txt file with pip freeze and uncomment
# the next three lines.

COPY API/requirements.txt /app/API/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/API/requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg -y


# Copy the app contents to the image
COPY ./ /app

#ENV PORT 8080
```

But when I run this with docker than it hangs while processing shell cmd.
[image]
But when I kill docker than I can see the process exc succ.
[image]

Please help this is quite tricky.

Comment: Where do these PNG files come from; is your program writing images directly out to the console?  Is there a plain-text error message that your program is producing that you can include in the question?  How can you tell that it's working or not working?

Comment: It is not giving error it just `print(cmd)` after that hangs up. If I kill the docker process that it prints result of `subprocess`. The image is my cmd shell afre docker run. Shell command not working in docker if called with thread.